# Mocking angular modules to pass karma testing

Tags: angularjs, flash, module, mocking, karma-jasmine

I recently implemented flash messages into my controller which has led to all of my karma tests failing.  I saw another post suggested making a fake module and injecting that in but it does not seem best practice.

Is there a simple way of mocking 'angular-flash' from my controller?

edit:

this is the start of the stack error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ShopTill due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flash due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'flash' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$injector/nomod?p0=flash
        at /Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1955
        at ensure (/Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1877)
        at module (/Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2192)
        at /Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4338
        at forEach (/Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336)
        at loadModules (/Users/edobrien/Documents/projects/Clothing-Retailer/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4364)
        at /Users/edobrien/Documents/proj
```

but it works when I look on localhost, so it must be an issue with the test.... any help?

Comment: You should mock the injectables that your controller requires. A unit test should only care about the stuff that it's testing, in your case, your controller.

Comment: yeah but it's the injected module that has broken the test, either I need to include the module somehow or stub it out

Comment: If you controller doesn't use anything from the module you could just load the module in your unit tests. I guess other factories in your module require it?

Comment: I've added my stack to the page